# Custom converter for Jooq Result

Tags: java, sql, type-conversion, jooq, modelmapper

Actually we are using `fetchInto()` to convert the results to list of object.

For example:

`Employee` pojo matching database table is employee.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = sql.select(Tables.Employee)
                                 .from(Tables.EMPLOYEE).fetchInto(Employee.class);
```

similarly, how could we convert the records we are fetching using joins?

For example:

`Customer` pojo matching database table is `customer`.

`Employee` pojo matching database table is `employee`.

```
sql.select(<<IWantAllFields>>).from(Tables.CUSTOMER)
                              .join(Tables.EMPLOYEE)
                              .on(Tables.EMPLOYEE.ID.equal(Tables.CUSTOMER.EMPLOYEE_ID))
                              .fetchInto(?);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select all fields from a joined table source, simply select "none":

```
Result<Record> result =
sql.select().from(Tables.CUSTOMER)
            .join(Tables.EMPLOYEE)
            .on(...)
            .fetch();
```

jOOQ will then introspect the known table source and generate all column references for you. One way to create a POJO relationship is to use one of the various [`Result.intoGroups()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#intoGroups%28org.jooq.Field,%20java.lang.Class%29) methods. E.g.:

```
Map<Integer, List<Customer>> map =
result.intoGroups(CUSTOMER.EMPLOYEE_ID, Customer.class);
```

This will produce a map of `List<Customer>` pojos per `EMPLOYEE_ID` value.

On a side-note: As with any mapping operation that calls upon the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html), mapping might not work as expected when your `JOIN` operation produces two times the same column name (e.g. `CUSTOMER.ID` and `EMPLOYEE.ID`) - as the `DefaultRecordMapper` doesn't know what table a particular column originates from.

For more sophisticated mapping, you should probably implement your own [`RecordMapperProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/)

Comment: Actually I want fields from both the tables.

Comment: And I think ModelMapper support this feature, but I am trying to convert each record to custom object it failed. Any help?  http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/jooq-integration/

Comment: I'm afraid that jOOQ currently doesn't support one-to-many mapping of results to POJOs. The above hints are the best you can do so far...

Comment: Thanks, now I am trying to implement custom mapping using RecordMapperProvider.

Comment: Great. Let me know how it goes. If any questions arise, related to `RecordMapperProvider`, just ask a new SO question, or ask for help on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user)

Comment: I'm just learning JOOQ, but I believe the result.intoGroups(Field, Class) will fail for POJOs if the join result set has multiple columns with the same name. So in this case, your customer name might get the value for the employee name or vice versa with no exceptions thrown. It seems result.intoGroups(Table) is MUCH safer but please correct me if I'm wrong as I've only been using JOOQ for 30 minutes or so :)